# Update rows greater than 1 using Row_number to match the value in row 1

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table in postgresql. The case number is not the pK. I wanto to update tall the rows with the same case number to have the same locaiton.

| Casenumber | location | Rownumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3058673 | N 7 AVE AND W DUNLAP AVE | 1 |
| 3058673 | SAA | 2 |
| 3058673 | SAA | 3 |
| 3058321 | 3900 - 3600 E THOMAS RD | 1 |
| 3058321 | SAME | 2 |
| 3058321 | SAME | 3 |

I have used row numbers so that most of those with an address are row number 1. I want to update the subsequent rows with the location from 1.

I have tried several codes

```
update locationupdate
set "location"= (Select "location" from locationupdate where locationnumber>1 and casenumber='3052161')
where casenumber='3058673'
and locationnumber>1;
```

made all of the rows greater than 1 null
I have tried self join

```
update locationupdate
set "location"= (Select b.locationnumber from locationupdate where b.locationnumber>1)
from locationupdate as a JOIN locationupdate as b on a.casenumber=b.casenumber'
and a.locationnumber>1
```

My subquery returns more than one result it won't work

```
update locationupdate
set "location"= b.location
from locationupdate as a JOIN (Select * from locationupdate where locationnumber=1) as b on a.casenumber=b.casenumber
and a.locationnumber>1;
```

updates all the rest of the rows to the same and doesn't work for each case number

Can someone point m in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the table you are updating in the from-clause:

```
CREATE TABLE test (case_nr int,location text,location_nr int);

INSERT INTO test VALUES
(3058673,   'N 7 AVE AND W DUNLAP AVE', 1),
(3058673,   'SAA',  2),
(3058673,   'SAA',  3),
(3058321,   '3900 - 3600 E THOMAS RD',  1),
(3058321,   'SAME', 2),
(3058321,   'SAME', 3);

UPDATE test SET location = b.location 
FROM test b 
WHERE b.case_nr   = test.case_nr 
AND b.location_nr = 1;

SELECT * FROM test;


3058673 "N 7 AVE AND W DUNLAP AVE"  1
3058673 "N 7 AVE AND W DUNLAP AVE"  2
3058673 "N 7 AVE AND W DUNLAP AVE"  3
3058321 "3900 - 3600 E THOMAS RD"   1
3058321 "3900 - 3600 E THOMAS RD"   2
3058321 "3900 - 3600 E THOMAS RD"   3
```